# two file comparison in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a map reduce to compare two large file in hdfs. any thoughts how to achieve that. Or if there is nay other way to do the comparison because file size is very large, so thought map-reduce would be an ideal approach.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in 2 steps.

1. First make the line number to be the part of text files:

Say initial file looks like:

```
I am awesome
He is my best friend
```

Now, convert this to something like this:

```
1,I am awesome
2,He is my best friend
```

This may well be done by a MapReduce job itself or some other tool.

2. Now write a MapReduce step where in mapper emit the line number as the key and rest of the actual sentence as value. Then in reducer just compare the values. As and when it doesn't match emit out the line number (the key) and the payloads, whatever you may want here. Also if the count of the `values` is just 1 then also it is a mismatch.

**EDIT: Better approach**

Better still what you can do is, just emit the complete line read at a time in the mapper as the key and make the value a number, say 1. So taking my above example your mapper output would be as follows:

```
< I am awesome,1 >

< He is my best friend,1 >
```

And in reducer just check the count of `values`, if it isn't 2, you have a mismatch.

But there is one catch in this approach, if there is a possibility of exactly same line occurring at two different places then instead of checking for the length of `values` for a given key in reducer, you should be checking it to be a multiple of 2.

Comment: Hi Amar, Thanks for your response. But my files has item ids which appears in both files. and I need to compare if both ids are same and their corresponding values.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is there in the files, right? By compare you meant binary compare, right? Instead of `I am awesome` in your file you may have an id, say `1234456565`.

Comment: I meant to say, suppose i have these two files. File 1 contains 
ID: 1 …..
ID: 2….
ID: 3….

File 2

ID: 5…..
ID: 3….
ID: 6….

Now for this comparison. I need to first match IDs from both files, than compare. and order is not grunted.

Comment: Do one thing, post a snippet from both your files and elaborate on the question.

Comment: I need to comapare whole line which start with ID and in the same line they have several other values.

Comment: This is even simpler. Just emit your ID as the key from the mapper and rest as value. And in the reducer compare the values. You get what I am saying here?

Comment: Not sure. My problem is map-reduce takes only key-value pair, right? I need to read from two files and than do the comparison. So exactly hot to pass two files as input and treat them as two different files and take id from first file, search in second one and than do the comparison.

Comment: You can certainly pass more than one input files to a MapReduce job. Mappers will split the input data among themselves to process as per the split size set by relevant configuration. Now, regardless of the data being read from which file, if you emit the key-value pair to be as <ID,rest-of-value> pair from reducer and count the number of values you get in the reducer per key (per ID),and also match the values then you can be sure of the match.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be, put line number as count in map job. 
There are two files like below :

File 1:
I am here --Line 1
I am awesome -- Line 2
You are my best friend -- Line 3

File 2 also similar kind

Now your map job output should be like , < I am awesome, 2>...

Once you done with Map job for both the file, you have two record(key,value) which has same value to reduce.

At the time of reduce, you can either compare the counter or generate the output as ,  and so on. If the line is exist in the different location too than out put could be  which indicates that this line is mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for comparing files with keys. In your case if you know that your ID's are unique, you could emit the ID's as keys in the map, the entire record as value. Lets say your file has ID,Line1 then emit  as key and  as value from mapper.

In the shuffle and sort phase, the ID's will be sorted and you will get an iterator with data from both the files. ie, the records from both files with same ID will end up in same iterator.

Then in the reducer, compare both the values from the iterator and if they match move on with next record. Else, if they do not match write them to an output.

I have done this and it worked like a charm.

**Scenario - No matching key**
If there is no matching ID between two files, they will have only one iterator value.

Scenario 2 - Duplicate keys
If the files have duplicate keys, the iterator will have more than 2 values.

**Note:** You should compare the values only when the iterator has only 2 values. 
**Tip:**The iterator will not have values in order always. To identify the value from a particular file, in the mapper add a small indicator at the end of the line like Line1;file1
Line1;file2
Then on the reducer you will be able to identify which value belongs to which mapper.